# Javascript replace every , except last one

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question.

I have the following code:

```
 $('.test').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var arrayProducts = new Array();

        $('.tableProducts').each(function(i)
        {
            if(typeof arrayProducts[i] == "undefined")
                arrayProducts[i] = new Array();
            $(this).find(':input').each(function(k)
            {
                if(k == 1)
                {
                    var test = $(this).val();
                    arrayProducts[i].push(test+":0:0.0000");
                }
                else{
                    arrayProducts[i].push($(this).val());
                }
            });

        });
        var string = arrayProducts.join("|");
        var productstring = string.replace(/,/g, ":");
        $('#optionstring').append(productstring);
    })
```

The result is for example: `Opel:20:1:1:1:Suzuki:500:1:1:1`

As you can see, that string is a combination of 2 products(`Opel:20:1:1:1 and Suzuki:500:1:1:1`)

Is it possible to create that after every last input, the ',' wont be changed into ':' like this:

```
Opel:20:1:1:1,Suzuki:500:1:1:1
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="optiondiv">
    <table class="tableOptions">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Option</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Title</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Input Type</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Required</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Position</b>: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="addproduct">Add</button>
                <button class="deleteProduct">Delete</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="title">
            </td>

            <td>
                <select class="input">
                    <option value="select">Drop-down</option>
                    <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
                    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                    <option value="multi">Multiple Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="required">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="position">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="hiddenOption">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Option</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Title</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Input Type</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Required</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Position</b>: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="addproduct">Add</button>
                <button class="deleteProduct">Delete</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="title">
            </td>

            <td>
                <select class="input">
                    <option value="select">Drop-down</option>
                    <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
                    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                    <option value="multi">Multiple Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="required">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="position">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="productdiv">
    <table class="tableProducts">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>SKU</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Default Quantity</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Position</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Default</b>:</td>
            <td><b>User defined</b>:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sku">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="quantity">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="position">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="isDefault">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="userdefined">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="hiddenTemplate">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>SKU</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Default Quantity</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Position</b>:</td>
            <td><b>Default</b>:</td>
            <td><b>User defined</b>:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sku">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="quantity">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="position">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="isDefault">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="userdefined">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<hr class="hr">
<button class="addOption">Create option</button>
<button class="deleteOption">Delete option</button>
<hr>
<button class="generateString">Genereer string</button>
<button class="test">Genereer products</button>
<hr>
<label>
    Optionstring:<p id="optionstring"></p>
</label>
```

Comment: Thus you need a String as the output ?

Comment: So you want to change the `syntax` of the array? Will be hard i think.

Comment: @Arg0n I think his expected output is a string and not an array literal

Comment: This makes no sense. This is an array. What you want is an object.

Comment: Don't wane change the syntax of the array, wanne change the output of the array :P

Comment: @KoenvandeSande horrible practice. nightmare for anyone going into your code later on and trying to figure out what you're doing. Highly recommend a different approach.

Comment: where do you get the output from?

Comment: I guess `car` is JSON string, not array

Comment: @KoenvandeSande What output? `car.toString()`? That would output `"Car,200,1,1,0"`.

Comment: The way your question is written, you are saying that you want to alter array syntax, which doesn't make sense. If you actually mean that you want to take the array and convert it to some sort of display string, then show what you've tried and we'll help you understand what went wrong.

Comment: ...and `car.replace(/,/g, ":");` won't do anything except throw an error,.

Comment: I've edited the post so my code is complete visible, I may have written the question wrong but I hope you now understand what I mean

Comment: @KoenvandeSande More clear now, but can you show the HTML also?

Comment: @KoenvandeSande Check my answer.

Comment: Sure, gimme sec.

Comment: Oh, so I think your issue is that the nested arrays are only getting joined when you call `.join("|")` on the outer array, which makes the inner arrays get the default `,` separator, which you're then trying to replace. Seems like you should be doing a `.join(":")` on each individual inner array. Sort of hard to tell with a partial example though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` to split the string in the right place. In your particular case - split at every colon preceding a letter.

Replace: `var productstring = string.replace(/,/g, ":")`

with: `var productstring = string.split(/:(?=\D)/g).join(', ')`.

```js
var str = 'Opel:20:1:1:1:Suzuki:500:1:1:1:Mazda:6:1:1:1';

console.log(str.split(/:(?=\D)/g).join(', '));
```

Comment: While I don't know why the poster wants this, this answer does provide the requested result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array with arrays and you need to join the inner array with colon, you coul map the inner joined arrays and join it the with comma.

```js
var cars = [['Opel', 20, 1, 1, 1], ['Suzuki', 500, 1, 1, 1]],
    string = cars.map(a => a.join(':')).join();

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming looking at your code you have an array similar as below.

```js
var arrayProducts = [['Opel','20','1','1','1'],['Suzuki','500','1','1','1']];

var productstring = '';
for(subarr of arrayProducts) { 
    productstring += (productstring !== '' ? ', ' : '') + subarr.join(':') 
}

console.log(productstring ); //Opel:20:1:1:1, Suzuki:500:1:1:1
```